# Inserting element into QSet class

Tags: qt

I have following class:

```
class UnionFuzzySet : public FuzzySet
{
public:
    UnionFuzzySet();
    void addActivatedFuzzySet(const ActivatedFuzzySet &set);
    double getValue(double value);

private:
    QSet<ActivatedFuzzySet> subConclusions;
};
```

And method addActivatedFuzzySet(...):

```
void UnionFuzzySet::addActivatedFuzzySet(const ActivatedFuzzySet &set)
{
    this->subConclusions << set;
}
```

It doesn't work with compiling error:

c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore\qhash.h:882: ошибка: C2665: 'qHash' : none of the 16 overloads could convert all the argument types
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(62): could be 'uint qHash(char)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(63): or       'uint qHash(uchar)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(64): or       'uint qHash(signed char)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(65): or       'uint qHash(ushort)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(66): or       'uint qHash(short)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(67): or       'uint qHash(uint)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(68): or       'uint qHash(int)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(69): or       'uint qHash(ulong)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(77): or       'uint qHash(long)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(78): or       'uint qHash(quint64)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(86): or       'uint qHash(qint64)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(87): or       'uint qHash(QChar)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(88): or       'uint qHash(const QByteArray &)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(89): or       'uint qHash(const QString &)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(90): or       'uint qHash(const QStringRef &)'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore/qhash.h(91): or       'uint qHash(const QBitArray &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(const ActivatedFuzzySet)'

Please, tell me, where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 6):

`QSet` uses hash table inside. But to store item in hash table, you should be able to calculate item's hash. `qHash` function does calculate hash for item.

As you can see, it is some predefined overloads, that allow you to calculate hash for standard types, but if you want to store `ActivatedFuzzySet` you should define function `qHash` that accepts your `ActivatedFuzzySet`, like that:

```
uint qHash(const ActivatedFuzzySet& value)  
{
    //calculate hash here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

all data type can t be set as template in a qhash.
please, read the qt documentation page : http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qset.html#details

If you set a pointer to your type instead of the type it should be ok

Comment: But he wants a set based on item equivalence, not on pointer equivalence.